# How to query sequelize model by association, but include all associated objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

### Trying to query by all association's attribute, but get all associations

```
# FAQs: { id: 1, name: 'How to do it?' }, { id: 2, name: 'How to FIX it?' }
# tags: { id: 1, slug: 'api' }, { id: 2, slug: 'beta' }
# taggings: { id: 1, faqId: 1, mainEntityId: 1, mainEntityType: 'faq' }, { id: 2, faqId: 1, mainEntityId: 2, mainEntityType: 'faq' }

const query = { slugs: ['api'] }
const foundFAQs = await this.models.FAQ.findAll({
  where: {
    '$taggings.tag.slug$': { $in: query.slugs },
  },
  include: [{
    model: this.models.Tagging,
    as: "taggings",           
    include: [{
      model: this.models.Tag,         
      as: 'tag',
    }],        
  }],
})
```

#### My model definition:

```
models.Tagging.belongsTo(models.Tag, { as: 'tag', onDelete: 'cascade' });
models.Tag.hasMany(models.Tagging, { as: 'taggings', onDelete: 'cascade' });
models.Tag.belongsToMany(models.FAQ, { through: models.Tagging, as: 'faqs' });
models.FAQ.hasMany(models.Tagging, { as: 'taggings', onDelete: 'cascade' });
models.FAQ.belongsToMany(models.Tag, { through: models.Tagging, as: 'tags' });
```

### What do you expect to happen?

I want to get all FAQs what has associated TAG `api` and have all its tags.

Object:
    { 
    id: 1, 
    name: 'How to do it?',
    tags: [
    { id: 1, slug: 'api' },
    { id: 2, slug: 'beta' }
    ]
    }

### What is actually happening?

Query returns object:
    { 
      id: 1, 
      name: 'How to do it?',
      tags: [
        { id: 1, slug: 'api' }
      ]
    }

#### Output

```
SELECT \"faq\".\"id\", \"faq\".\"name\", \"faq\".\"bankId\", \"faq\".\"priority\", 
\"faq\".\"publishedLocales\", \"faq\".\"createdAt\", \"faq\".\"updatedAt\", \"taggings\".\"id\" 
AS \"taggings.id\", \"taggings\".\"tagId\" AS \"taggings.tagId\", \"taggings\".\"locked\" 
AS \"taggings.locked\", \"taggings\".\"sdkId\" AS \"taggings.sdkId\", \"taggings\".\"guideId\" 
AS \"taggings.guideId\", \"taggings\".\"newsId\" AS \"taggings.newsId\", \"taggings\".\"faqId\" 
AS \"taggings.faqId\", \"taggings\".\"apiId\" AS \"taggings.apiId\", \"taggings\".\"createdAt\" 
AS \"taggings.createdAt\", \"taggings\".\"updatedAt\" AS \"taggings.updatedAt\", \"taggings->tag\".\"id\" 
AS \"taggings.tag.id\", \"taggings->tag\".\"name\" AS \"taggings.tag.name\", \"taggings->tag\".\"slug\" 
AS \"taggings.tag.slug\", \"taggings->tag\".\"tagType\" AS \"taggings.tag.tagType\", \"taggings->tag\".\"mainEntityId\" 
AS \"taggings.tag.mainEntityId\", \"taggings->tag\".\"createdAt\" 
AS \"taggings.tag.createdAt\", \"taggings->tag\".\"updatedAt\" 
AS \"taggings.tag.updatedAt\" FROM \"faqs\" AS \"faq\" INNER JOIN \"taggings\" 
AS \"taggings\" ON \"faq\".\"id\" = \"taggings\".\"faqId\" LEFT OUTER JOIN \"tags\" 
AS \"taggings->tag\" ON \"taggings\".\"tagId\" = \"taggings->tag\".\"id\" WHERE \"faq\".\"bankId\" = 'bank.csas' 
AND \"taggings->tag\".\"slug\" IN ('faq') ORDER BY \"faq\".\"priority\" DESC;
```

**Dialect:** postgres

**Dialect version:** pg@^6.1.0

**Database version:** PostgreSQL 10.1

**Sequelize version:** 4.23.2

**Tested with the latest release:** No (4.23.2)

**Node:** 8.6.0

I am not sure if it is a bug or I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your model and relation code? Also, an alternative might be to approach from the other direction; find the tag and `include` the related FAQs.

Comment: @Will model definition added. Yes, it's an alternative, but I would have to quite difficult map result and when I'd be looking for two tags, will have duplicates here, isn't it?

Comment: Probably. Have you tried moving the where clause into the include for Tag?

Comment: @Will Yes, I have. It's the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to include all related data for each record, but filter those records on that related data. You're going to want to get Sequelize to generate SQL similar to:

```
SELECT "faq"."id", ....
FROM "faqs" AS "faq"
INNER JOIN "taggings" AS "taggings" ON "faq"."id" = "taggings"."faqId"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "tags" AS "taggings->tag" ON "taggings"."tagId" = "taggings->tag"."id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "tags" AS "taggings->tagdata" ON "taggings"."tagId" = "taggings->tagdata"."id"
WHERE "faq"."bankId" = 'bank.csas' AND "taggings->tag"."slug" IN ('faq')
ORDER BY "faq"."priority" DESC;
```

Something like this might work:

```
const foundFAQs = await this.models.FAQ.findAll({
  where: {
    '$taggings.tag.slug$': { $in: query.slugs },
  },
  include: [{
    model: this.models.Tagging,
    as: "taggings",           
    include: [{
      model: this.models.Tag,         
      as: 'tag',
    },{
      model: this.models.Tag,         
      as: 'tagdata',
    }],
  }],
})
```

The idea here is that you're performing a join on which you are filtering, and then another join to get the extra records for the filtered rows.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me today -- nested `includes`:

```
getReferralPlanForThisCode(parent, args, context) {
    let {referralCode} = args;
    return Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => {
            let referralPlan = connectors.ReferralPlans.findAll({
                include: [{
                    model: connectors.ReferralCodes,
                    where: {unique_referral_code: referralCode},
                    include: [{
                        model: connectors.epUserData, as: 'referrer',
                    }],
                }],
            })
            return referralPlan;
        })
        .then(referralPlan => {
            return referralPlan;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```